# Как лучше организовать связь sqlite с mysql в андроид приложении

Tags: java, android

Вопрос в следующем, при разработке android-приложения (IDE: Android Studio) можно пойти следующими путями: использовать `java` - `xml` или же юзать `html` + `css` + `js`. Да, я понимаю, что 2ой способ это мягко сказать неказисто (: Цель в том: что бы написать простенькое приложение, которое будет юзать `sqlite` и синхронить ее с `mysql` (в частном случаю для определенного юзера).

В следствии чего, вопросы:

- Можно ли организовать обмен данными `sqlite - java - html`? К примеру, вывод в `Html` данных из `sqlite` с помощью `java`.
- Или лучше юзать 1 метод?

Заманчиво то, что можно использовать css за счет чего делать приложение более динамичным.

P.S. Да, я в курсе про разные фреймворки типо cordova и т.п.

P.S.S. Прошу без фанатизма и объективно. Буду благодарен за примеры.

Comment: А вам зачем приложение? насколько критично надо чтобы работало в оффлайне? как объем данных? ( я к тому что может вам достаточно PWA?)

Comment: PWA, наврятле, подойдет ибо приложение должно работать и без сети, предоставляя пользователю полный функционал. Объемы данных совсем небольшие да и большой математики тоже нет.

Comment: Для cordova/ionic есть например такое решение с fallback на  браузер https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/ по сути вы общаетесь через уже написанный бридж java sqlite html